# Getting Node.js to work

Tags: apt, nodejs

My computer is running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I was trying to get a simple hello world file to work with node, but was unable to. I ran the command `node hello.js` and nothing happened. I ran `apt-get remove nodejs` and then `apt-get install nodejs` and finally `apt-get install npm` This seemed to work, however when I run `node -v` nothing happens. No error, just nothing. `which node` ouptuts `/usr/sbin/node` What can I do to attempt to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Default nodejs that comes with Ubuntu can be executed the following way:

```
nodejs -v
```

If you upgrade to the latest using https://github.com/nodesource/distributions, you will be able to execute it with

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading nodejs and install it

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm